# What is the rpm package checksum for?

Tags: bash, rpm

I had to download few rpm packages, some of these packages are provided with checksums, what are they for ?
Are they necessary to have the rpm installed ?

Comment: Check the answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36445697/6004486) to see what checksums are used for and how use them for verifying file integrity. And no, they're not necessary to install the rpm; just an added feature that's nice to have - especially when things don't work as expected and you want to find the source of a problem.

Comment: RPMs have built-in checksums and GPG verification, so an external checksum is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checksums are used to make sure you downloaded the complete file and or wasn't modified by a third party or a bad connection.

Many sites that host files will also host a checksum file that it can be compared against. To run that comparison for, say, an md5 checksum you could do the following:

Given `downloaded.file` is the downloaded file, and you have a checksum (file.md5) file that looks like this

```
8ead7f214e53482b06ef82727d8ba4e4 downloaded.file
```

You would run

```
md5sum -c file.md5
```

The output would be

```
downloaded.file: OK
```

if the file has a matching sum. If the sum is *not* matching, you know that the file that you received is not the same as the file that the host intended. Whether it's malicious or not, you know you need to retry your download.

Comment: While this is useful, could you perhaps add how one would compare checksums to ensure they match?

Answer (score 0):

While what dave-ross said (a long time ago) about checksums is true for *any* file, the rpm files have a checksum stored in the rpm database, which by the way will not match with the checksum calculated with the md5sum command called directly on the file. This is because the former is not calculated only with the bits of the rpm file, like the latter is (like calling md5sum on any kind of file), but it takes into consideration other stuff (like the rpm headers).

This checksum is internally used among other properties by the rpm verify options:

> rpm {-V|--verify} [select-options] [verify-options]
>
> Verifying a package compares information about the installed files in
> the package with information about the files taken from the package
> metadata stored in the rpm database. Among other things, verifying
> compares the size, digest, permissions, type, owner and group of each
> file. Any discrepancies are displayed. Files that were not installed
> from the package, for example, documentation files excluded on
> installation using the "--excludedocs" option, will be silently
> ignored.

Mainly, if you change a file installed by an rpm, rpm -V will notice. e.g., I guess this is used by rpm installations when checking if a configuration file has been changed, to warn you and create the corresponding rpmsave or rpmnew files, but it also could be used as a security feature.

This checksum can be seen by using the query option query format:

```
~> rpm -qp --qf '%{SIGMD5}' $anRpm
b2aad9123e965f4366d64150931e1cbb
~> md5sum $anRpm
673c14e5e70b2cdc2f5771c92dbf16d7 $anRpm
```

However, I have not been able to find a clear reference to this query format option or generally a list of them: [queryformat in rpm.org](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/queryformat.html)

Apparently other algorythms could be used for generating the rpm digest, but I have not found a clear reference for this either. [This other post is about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062375/how-to-build-the-rpm-package-with-sha-256-checksum-for-files)

On top of all this, rpms can be "signed" with a GPG Key with the --add-sign option.